# Send commands remotely to mobile app in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, push, remotecommand

I am developing a mobile (Xamarin.IOS) and a desktop app (C# Winforms) for our small start-up for internal use. I want to be able to send commands (not remote notifications) to the client (mobile app) through our main desktop app.

For example; I want all our employees using our mobile app to perform certain task, let's say, show a popup window with specific text when they open up the app. Any ideas about how to implement such kind of thing? Is is technically possible to tell a device to remotely execute certain management commands?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is an incredibly broad question, but you might look at something like SignalR

Comment: easiest way to solve this would probably be using a server. For example  the server could store a JSON with "qued commands" which the client request at startup (and/or at intervals), which details what command should be performed and maybe how longe the qued command should live for (unless the server handles this on its own.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this.

A Microsoft MVP, Mark Arteaga, suggests using Azure Functions-HTTP Triggers to do this. He [presented this](https://pt.slideshare.net/MarkArteaga/serverless-computing-with-azure-functions-and-xamarin?next_slideshow=1) in multiple Microsoft events and also has a [Github repo](https://github.com/redbitdev/RedBit.Ai.Demo) where he implements it in a sample mobile app.

So whenever you need to, you would send commands through Azure Functions to the client using similar, and if you want to go one step further, you can even look into implementing it with Backgrounding using [Shiny](https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny)